# Sharepoint 2013 - Create group

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to create a Sharepoint 2013 (autohosted) group. In AppManifest I set Permissions> Site collection> Managed. Unfortunately I can not use Full-control.

```
var collGroups = ClientContextAppWeb.Web.SiteGroups;
ClientContextAppWeb.Load(collGroups);
ClientContextAppWeb.ExecuteQuery();

if (!collGroups.Any(a => a.Title.Equals("IT Helpdesk Admins")))
{
    var groupInfo = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.GroupCreationInformation()
    {
        Title = "IT Helpdesk Admins"
    };

    collGroups.Add(groupInfo);
    ClientContextAppWeb.Web.Update();
    ClientContextAppWeb.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

An error occurs when creating group - ServerUnauthorizedAccessException

Are there other options to create groups?

Answer (score 0):

It can read value at the top level but when if try to query for webs.Webs, web.Lists or web.RootFolder, this is when you get the exception.  With a full user account it dont have the problem, but for others users will only have limited access to certain areas of the site, i.e. a particular document library.